# How to correctly use CSS import for SFC without duplication?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am working on a large scaled project with Single File Components. Everything is fine except CSS including.

For the project I need bootstrap 4 and other global styles. But if I do not include them into each component, the build process failed. And if I include them into each component, the generated CSS files are too big because of duplicated CSS code :-/.

So how to properly handle this problem?

Thanks

Comment: still having issues with this. We have a massive app and a component library. We want a sass file per component & use bootstrap5. If we want to use any helper classes we have to import everything into the components. Using @nuxtjs/style-resources does not seem to make variables or helper classes available I components.

Answer (score 0):

Include them in `<style></style>` block of the root component. Notice that CSS `@import` is considered as anti-pattern, so build global CSS in one or several files before production.

```
<template>
  <div id="app"></div>
</template>

<style>
  @import url("https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css");
</style>
```

Or put the `<link></link>` to them into the `<head></head>` of the index.html.

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  ...
</head>
```